# FTP: Jail user to Home folder

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

Using Centos7 and vsftpd I would like to chroot the user "testftp" to his home folder /home/testftp. 
The client uses WinSCP on Windows.

passwd:

> testftp:x:1001:1001::/home/testftp/:/bin/bash

vsftpd.conf

> chroot_local_user=YES 
>  chroot_list_enable=YES 
>   chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list (this list contains 1 user)

When trying to FTP with the 1 user in the list, everything works except that user is of course not chrooted to his home directory

However when trying to login with the testftp user I get the following error:

> Disconnected from server 
>    Connection failed. 
>    OOPS: chroot